# Why isn't my image showing?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have the following Python script:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy

path = '/my_path'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith('first'):
            img1 = numpy.asarray(Image.open(root + '/' + file))
        if file.startswith('second'):
            img2 = numpy.asarray(Image.open(root + '/' + file))

    img1.show()
    img2.show()
```

When I run the code, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    img1.show()
NameError: name 'img1' is not defined
```

How can I display the images, provided that I would like to read `img1` and `img2` first?

Thanks.

Comment: If nothing starts with 'first' then img1 wouldn't be defined, and same goes for img2. Shouldn't you place img1 and img2 directly under where it's defined?

Comment: Also, img1 and img2 will be equal to the last images found, which I think is undesired behaviour

Comment: And `numpy` `array` doesn't have a `show` method, you should assign `img1` and `img2` to the image opened by `Image`, not the array parsed by `asarray`.

Comment: `img1` and `img2`, **if** they get defined by the `for` loop, aren't PIL `Image` objects, they're whatever `numpy.asarray()` returns. From the error message it sounds like the first one wasn't. If you want to display them, store the result of calling`Image.open()` in separate variables and call their `show()` methods. You can pass the same result to `asarray()` before or after doing thisl.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a scope issue. If you initialize img1 and img2 right after the first for loop that should do the trick.